# Would Wake Locks Help App with Foreground Service on Oreo Not Get Killed by Android?

Tags: android

I've written a music player app (EBT Music Player in Google Play). It plays media files stored locally on the device.

This app targets API version 27. It uses a foreground service to play music. This foreground service has a notification with the following flags:

FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE.

The service is started with a call to startForeground. The service is bound. 
Unfortunately, the app is killed after a period of minutes or hours, on an Android 8 phone that I bought (Nokia 6). I don't know if this is because of a bug in Android, or in my app. I do know that the device was not low on memory.

Would this app be less likely to be killed by the system if it used wake locks?

Is there anything else I should be doing to help the app avoid being killed?

[Bug report on Nokia community site](https://community.phones.nokia.com/support/discussions/topics/7000017413)

Comment: Doze (which is probably what is killing the service) releases wakelocks in 8.0 so I doubt it will do anything